# mosquitto running as service does not work but manually does

Tags: mqtt, nodered

if I run mosquitto manually `mosquitto`

i can connect to it and everything works perfectly

but if I run mosquitto as a service 
`sudo service mosquitto start`

then it doesen't respond and nothing works even though `sudo service mosquitto status` says its active

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you testing it? How do youi know it does not work?

Comment: node-red says it cant connect to broker and my esp's using mqtt cant connect to it either

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /var/lib/mosquitto
sudo rm mosquitto.db
sudo reboot
```

--> and everything was fine again...